# Allow Opera browser to understand what the next page is in a series of pages, so the user can do a keyboard shortcut to go to the next page

Tags: browser, pagination, opera

I forgot what the feature was called in the Opera Browser, but it allowed you to do a keyboard shortcut to go to the next or previous page in a series of pages on a website(This is not speaking of your history, but the browser somehow knows there's a series of pages connected to that page, and allows you to navigate through them). I'm trying to figure out how to code to allow Opera to know what the next page is, and if anyone can tell me what that feature is called, that'd be really helpful because I can't find anything about it on Google.

And does any other browser have this functionality? Is it worth putting time into this? Do other browsers have extensions for the functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called Fast Forward (activated when you press spacebar at bottom of page or Forward button).

You can give it a hint using a standard HTML `next` link relation:

```
<link rel="next" href="next_page.html">
```